# Blood Group Notation

Tags: hematology, history, blood-group

In a textbook, I encountered a notation used when writing blood groups down, which was "I" with the blood group type as a superscript. I was curious as to why the letter "I" is used in this notation and what it means. E.g. Iᴬ and Iᴮ.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Those are names of alleles involved in the ABO blood group system. The “I” stands for isoagglutinogen which is an antigen that causes agglutination of blood cells when reacting with a specific antibody (an isoagglutinin).